# Как реализовать аналог while (cin >> someValue)

Tags: c#

Перешёл с C++, на С#, и в тестовом задании требуется реализовать считывание "некоторого количества строк в массив".
Пробовал использовать конструкцию данного вида:

```
var currentString;
while (currentString = Console.ReadLine())
```

Но к сожалению C#, не позволяет провернуть такой трюк. Подскажите как можно реализовать аналог считывания до конца ввода.

Comment: _такой трюк_ - а что этот трюк должен сделать то? Подозреваю, что что-то такое надо `while ((currentString = Console.ReadLine()).Length > 0)`

Comment: почему просто не воспользоваться человекочитаемым кодом? `do { currentString = Console.ReadLine(); } while (currentString.Length > 0)`

Comment: Ну или так, да.